# TmxMapLoader doesn't understand floats

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled, tmx

When i tryin to load a map with TmxMapLoader like that:

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/TestMap.tmx");
```

i receive something like that:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15.1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader$Element.getIntAttribute(XmlReader.java:646)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.loadObject(TmxMapLoader.java:562)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.loadObjectGroup(TmxMapLoader.java:548)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.loadTilemap(TmxMapLoader.java:233)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:130)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:109)
at net.desu.Play.show(Play.java:71)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
at net.desu.LevelMenu$1.clicked(LevelMenu.java:63)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:85)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:57)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:345)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:297)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:209)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

The map is created by [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) editor

Can somebody explain to me what am i doing wrong? Link to map [here](http://pastebin.com/1yVsxqU1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update libgdx, that stack trace correlates to a rather old version. Floats have been supported very a long time.